# Javascript - Do something on cookie add

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've already searched for the answer but seems I can't found the answer.
My plan is to show alert after cookie on add.

I've set cookie exists after 5 seconds with setTimeout.
**Script**

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        document.cookie = "username=Billy Joe";
    }, 5000);
```

my approach is I use this code to check if the cookie exists or not.

```
if(!getCookie("username")){
    alert("Cookie doesn't exists");
}else{
    alert("Cookie exists");
}
```

But look's like is only check on the first load, not after the cookie on add.

 My question is how to show the alert after cookie has been added?
Thank you so much

Comment: You have to be more precisely in your question. If you set the cookie, you already know that your cookie is set. So, for me, it makes no sense to add a check afterwards within your `setTimeout` function. If you want to have some parallelism, e.g., that you check independently whether your cookie is set, I recommend to use events or promises to handle asynchronous calls.

Comment: @Guybrush Thank you for your suggestion. Next time I will be more precisely on making a question. And yes true, It's make no sense to check the cookie inside the timeout because I can always checkcookie in it. My cookie is added dinamically from php file so I want to check the cookie outside the timeout function. True, I want to check it independently but seems like I can't find out the answer from the sources I've been search. Could you share some events to handle asynchronous calls independently / outside the timeout function? Thanks a lot Guy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've found a wrong API in this context since that API was for Mozilla web extension. Be aware of it. The only working technique is to use the `setInterval` function (cf. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22641766/Javascript-Call-function-as-soon-as-cookie-value-changes-Set-listener-for-changed-cookie-value.html). However, I would to prefer to do not set the cookie within that function since it makes no sense ;):

```
var handledCookie = false;     // Was the cookie already handled?
var cookieCheckId = undefined; // The id of the checker

var handleCookie = function() {
  if (!getCookie("username")){
    alert("Cookie doesn't exists");
  } else {
    clearInterval(cookieCheckId); // Unset the check
    handledCookie = true;         // Set the cookie handled
    alert("Cookie exists");
  }
};

handleCookie();

if (!handledCookie) { 
  cookieCheckId = setInterval(handleCookie, 5000); // Handle the cookies
}
```

So, if the cookie is created inside or outside your code, the `handleCookie` function will be called once. The check is done all 5 seconds. If the cookie was found, then the check will be disabled (`clearInterval`).

**Wrong!!! answer before**:

You can deal with events. There is an event that is fired if a cookie changes (cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged).

For example, you can use something like this:

```
browser.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function(changeInfo) {
  if(!getCookie("username")){
    alert("Cookie doesn't exists");
  } else {
    alert("Cookie exists");
  }
});
```

You can also take a look on the `changeInfo` and use that information to identify your cookie:

```
browser.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function(changeInfo) {
  let cookie = JSON.stringify(changeInfo.cookie);
  if (cookie.name === 'username') {
    alert("Cookie exists");
  }
});
```

However, then you have no check whether your cookie is non-existent.

Comment: Hi Guybrush! 
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I used your code and unfortunately I got this following error 
"TypeError: browser.cookies is undefined"

Comment: I'm sorry. That seems to be a new API and does not work in all browsers. I look it for your.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API was for web extensions. So they do not work on ordinary websites. However, I've corrected my answer and now, it should be working. There is no event or something else to handle cookies.

Comment: Hi Guybrush!
Thank you for your kindness for answering my question :)
With your new code, now It works like a charm.
a little question, 
Could you explain why would you put var cookieCheckId as "-1" ?
Why not empty string or null?
Thank you so much!

Comment: That has no special deeper sense. It may be better to set it to `undefined`. ;). Maybe, an upvote would looks good as a negative voted answer seems not to be a solution at last ;)

Comment: Hey Guybrush!
I already upvote this answer but don't know why It's still going down :(

Comment: No problem. It is how it is. Thank you Billy!

Comment: It has no support for iOS

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to show the alert after cookie has been added?

Easy, just do your check after you have added the cookie!

```
function checkCookie () {
  alert(getCookie("username") ? "Cookie exists!" : "Cookie doesn't exist!");
}

setTimeout(function () {
  document.cookie = "username=Billy Joe";
  checkCookie();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hello Alex! Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it. But I forgot to mention that checkCookie() function must be outside of time out because the cookie created dinamically from php, not inside the timeout. So how to I achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Time has progressed and there is a [Cookie Store API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cookie_Store_API) that provides `onchange` method. Unfortunately courtesy of Chrome-based browsers for now. Just adding it here in case somebody targets Chrome specifically.

Comment: It does have caveats - This feature is available only in HTTPS and is not widely supported

Answer (score -1):

Basically setTimeout is always run asynchronously so basically your if block is running before setting cookie value. you should use function after adding cookie. for example your timeout function is run/set cookie value after 5 second but your alter runs immediately reading the setTimeout code

Here is example is should work for you.

```
function checkCookie(){
    if(!getCookie("username")){
        alert("Cookie doesn't exists");
    }else{
        alert("Cookie exists");
    }
}

// check before add
checkCookie()

setTimeout(function(){
    document.cookie = "username=Billy Joe";
    // check after add
    checkCookie();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't understand why I should check the cookie when it is set by myself within the same code?

Comment: you can rename the function brother. checkCookie to alter cookie.

Comment: Ok, it could make sense if the function is reused somewhere else within the code and something useful is done by it. However, in this case, it would be better to use an extra function for handling the `true` case, isn't it? And then you can perform the extra function directly in the `setTimeout`, right?

Comment: it depends of what do you want to achieve. programming fun so always try to achieve one goal with at least 3 method.

Comment: Hello Syed!
Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.
But I forgot to mention that checkCookie() function must be outside of time out because the cookie created dinamically from php, not inside the timeout.
So how to I achieve that? 
Thank you!